# Why does the colon matter in vim remaps?

Tags: vim

What's the difference between these two remaps?

```
nnoremap ZZ :echo "Your Caps-lock is on."<cr>
nnoremap ZZ echo "Your Caps-lock is on."<cr>
```

The first displays a message in the command-area, the second prints the message into the buffer. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon switches vim to the command-line mode. See: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#mode-switching

Comment: Of course. The second example interprets me typing e c h o literally in normal mode, but the color switches to command mode. Thanks.

Comment: When I try to reproduce, it behaves as I would expect: 'e' goes to the end of word, 'c' 'h' changes one char to the left with 'o', then the sentence and newline are inserted.